# Registering Native Python Type to PySide QItemEditorFactory

Tags: python, qt, pyside

The [documentation](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QItemEditorFactory.html?highlight=qitemeditorfactory#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QItemEditorFactory.registerEditor) for `PySide.QtGui.QItemEditorFactory.registerEditor(type, creator)` says that `type` is a `PySide.QtCore.QVariant::Type`.  But this [page](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/pysideapi2.html#qvariant) says that

> When a method expects a QVariant::Type the programmer can use a string (the type name) or the type itself.

I have the Color example working and I've registered QtGui.QColor with a Editor Creator `factory.registerEditor(QtGui.QColor, ColorEditorCreator())` but I can't get any non Qt types to work.  When I provide a type the factory return the default text editor.

What would be the syntax to register a python native type or a python class to a custom editor creator?

```
factory.registerEditor(type(list), ListEditorCreator())
```

Thanks

---

**Update**:

Here is a code sample that launches a 3 row table with each value registered to the same editor and editor creator.  The editor is a QLineEdit but there's no actually editing.  My problem is that when I double click on the str and QVector3D values, the item editor factory invokes the creator and the QLineEdit visibly activates (and the `print("createWidget")` is called).

When I double click on the list value there is no QLineEdit activation and the print statement is not called. Why?

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

class MyEditor(QtGui.QLineEdit):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyEditor, self).__init__(parent)

    def getData(self):
        return ""

    def setData(self, data):
        pass

    def getList(self):
        return []

    def setList(self, data):
        pass

    def getVector(self):
        return QtGui.QVector3D()

    def setVector(self, data):
        pass

    mydata = QtCore.Property(str, getData, setData, user=True)

    mylist = QtCore.Property(list, getList, setList, user=True)

    myvec  = QtCore.Property(QtGui.QVector3D, getVector, setVector, user=True)

class MyCreator(QtGui.QItemEditorCreatorBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyCreator, self).__init__()

    def createWidget(self, parent):
        print("createWidget")
        return MyEditor(parent)

class Window(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        factory = QtGui.QItemEditorFactory()
        myCreator = MyCreator()
        factory.registerEditor(list, myCreator)
        factory.registerEditor(str, myCreator)
        factory.registerEditor(QtGui.QVector3D, myCreator)
        QtGui.QItemEditorFactory.setDefaultFactory(factory)
        self.createGUI()

    def createGUI(self):
        data = ((self.tr('Str'), "test"),
                (self.tr('List'), [4,5,6]),
                (self.tr('Vector'), QtGui.QVector3D()))
        table = QtGui.QTableWidget(len(data), 2)
        table.setHorizontalHeaderLabels([self.tr('Name'), self.tr('Value')])
        table.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        table.resize(150, 50)
        for i, (name, value) in enumerate(data):
            nameItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(name)
            valueItem = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
            valueItem.setData(QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole, value)
            table.setItem(i, 0, nameItem)
            table.setItem(i, 1, valueItem)
        table.resizeColumnToContents(0)
        table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)
        layout = QtGui.QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(table, 0, 0)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setWindowTitle(self.tr('Editor Factory'))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What evidence do you have that it "doesn't work"? I had no problem getting `createEditor` to return the appropriate editor for `dict`, `list`, `str`, etc. So you need to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the specific problem you're having.

Comment: @ekhumoro Thanks for helping but could you comment on the syntax that I provided with the python list?  Is that correct?

Comment: Using `type` is redundant, but assuming `ListEditorCreator` is a subclass of `QItemEditorCreatorBase`, the arguments seem correct. Why don't you think it works? What were you expecting?

Comment: The properties in your example don't seem to have any effect (commenting them out makes no difference). I suspect that the PySide implementation may be incomplete or broken in some obscure way. I would advise you to ditch the item-editor-factory approach, and use a custom item-delegate instead - it's much simpler.